# how i can take setOnCameraViewListener on Camera?

Tags: android, camera-view

My code is as following -

```
cameraView.setOnCameraViewListener(new OnCameraViewListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onCameraInit(List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes) {
            Camera.Size cameraPreviewSize = supportedPreviewSizes.get(supportedPreviewSizes.size() - 1);
            if (cameraPreviewSize.width > supportedPreviewSizes.get(0).width) {
                cameraPreviewSize = supportedPreviewSizes.get(0);
            }
            cameraView.setCameraPreviewSizeImageQuality(cameraPreviewSize, 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraSupportedPreviewSizes(List<Size> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Its giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cameraView.setOnCameraViewListener(new OnCameraViewListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraSupportedPreviewSizes(List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera.Size cameraPreviewSize = supportedPreviewSizes
                .get(supportedPreviewSizes.size() - 1);
        if (cameraPreviewSize.width > supportedPreviewSizes.get(0).width) {
            cameraPreviewSize = supportedPreviewSizes.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```